# How do i pass a value from google calendar through to another platform?

Tags: php

I need help on how to pass through a value from a google calendar appointment block to another platform.

I know how to create the hyperlink in google calendar but im not sure on how to send a value through. It wont be a standard value **for example** i  need to enter a ID number in the appointment fields and make the ID field a hyperlink which pulls that number through to the next platform.

Comment: Can you be more specific about what you are trying to pass? Is it the eventId? CalendarId? Something that doesn't already exist in Google Calendar?

Comment: So basically whatever value is put in the title field needs to pull through via a hyperlink and pass it to another page.

Comment: You can accomplish this using the [Google Calendar API](https://developers.google.com/calendar/). It has a bit of a learning curve if you have not worked with it before but the quickstart guide is a great jumping off point. If API programming is too much you could look into a data automation service like Zapier.